# Issue with my Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have done a small extension that change the default search engine and set the do not track function to on. The extension works, but it causes an issue on my website (and maybe others too).

On my website I have a settings page, to change some stuff, like the text color, the language. When I turn on the extension, the settings are not working any more. The buttons don't save my choices.

Edit: I noticed that the problem is coming from the "chrome_settings_overrides" part. If I take it off the buttons are working just fine again. Maybe something is blocking the POST request?

I have validate my website as a owner in the Google dev dashboard, but that don't change anything.

Here is the manifest.json :

```html
{
  "incognito": "spanning",
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.5",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/logo-16.png",
    "32": "images/logo-32.png",
    "48": "images/logo-48.png",
    "128": "images/logo-128.png"
  },
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
      "search_provider": {
         "encoding": "UTF-8",
         "favicon_url": "http://www.mywebsite/favicon.ico",
         "is_default": true,
         "keyword": "...",
         "name": "...",
         "search_url": "http://www.mywebsite/search/index.php?a=web&q={searchTerms}"
      }
  },
  "description": "...",
  "default_locale": "fr",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "scripts/background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/logo-16.png",
      "32": "images/logo-32.png",
      "48": "images/logo-48.png"
    },
    "default_title": "mywebsite"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
"permissions": [ "cookies", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "activeTab" ]
}
```

And I use this kind of button for my settings page:

```html
<form action="http://www.mywebsite.com/search/index.php?a=preferences" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
 <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="linkw" id="linkOffw" value="_top" {$linkOffw} />
   <strong>Non</strong> - Ne pas ouvrir les r&eacute;sultats dans un nouvel onglet.
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="linkw" id="linkOnw" value="_blank" {$linkOnw} />
   <strong>Oui</strong> - Ouvrir les r&eacute;sultats dans un nouvel onglet.
  </label>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Enregistrer mes pr&eacute;f&eacute;rences</button>
 <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" class="btn">Retour</a>
</form>
```

Do I need to set some permissions on my manifest or something like that?

Here is the background.js

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details) {
 details.requestHeaders.push({name: "DNT", value: "1"});
 return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]);

function iconClicked() {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        'url': 'http://www.mywebsite.com'
    });
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(iconClicked);
```

Comment: Could you also provide `background.js`? it's critical I guess

Comment: Hi Haibara Ai , thanks for your reply.
yes sorry :)
I edited my first post.

Comment: Any errors/messages in web console of the site (F12 key) or in [background page console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)?

Comment: Hello wOxxOm, thanks for your reply :)
No errors on both pages, site and background page.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you open your site manually via addressbar, not by clicking the extension's icon?

Comment: The problem is the same if i click on the extension's icon or if i open manually the site.
With the extension none of my settings buttons are working, and without the extension everything works just fine.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the double post, i noticed that the issue is coming from the "chrome_settings_overrides" part. When i take it off, the buttons are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue.
It was something stupid, so stupid that you don't think about it...
The problem came from the "search_url", i was not using HTTPS in my url, and you MUST use HTTPS.
Raaaaaaaaaaa ! But now that's fine, that's the most important things.
Thanks.